# Facebook Graph API - Inconsistency of user name language

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing my web app which uses the Facebook PHP SDK. I have read from other posts that the user get to choose the name they want to display in the only name field. Is that true?

My name can be in 2 languages: English and Chinese. But **when I test my app, it sometimes used my Chinese version, but when I reload, it always displays the English version.**

### PHP:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$user);
//the line was: $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
//name was always English back then
//but it cause the expired token problem
$username = $user_profile['first_name'] . " " .  $user_profile['last_name'];
echo $username;
```

### Output sometimes:

```
志榮 張 //By the way, the Chinese name suppose to be 張志榮
```

### Often outputs:

```
Daniel Cheung
```

Why is that so? Because the displayed name will be recorded, the data will look very inconsistent and it's hard to do work on that with my database.

Can I tell Facebook to send only the English name? Because when people use the English version of Facebook, they see my English name. Chinese Facebook always displays my Chinese name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `locale` parameter to your Graph API requests. Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#readmodifiers

With this, you should at least be able to retrieve consistent results.

Comment: but why the inconsistency? :/ do you know?

Comment: No. Ask Mark Zuckerberg :-)

Comment: Are you using the same access token all the time?

Comment: @DanielCheung: You can also post questions to the [Facebook Developer Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/). You can get an answers from Facebook Developers and S/W engineers. No need to bother Mark Zuckerberg. ;)

Comment: @WizKid I don't know :/, but I run the check login state on every page, it doesn't seem to output any problems

Comment: I would guess that name could be different for different access tokens.

Comment: @RahilArora I posted, but I think that group is definitely less active than StackOverflow. Not dare to dream someone would answer me.

Comment: Oh! Last time when I saw, that group was more active that SO! Anyways, I hope someone will get back to you soon.